# Clustering text file into segments

Tags: clustering, text-mining

I have a big text file (over 5 GB) of log files from some network devices. The log consists of outputs from these devices after performing many different commands on them. However outputs are not labeled or seperated in any way. When one output ends next starts, often without even a new empty line between. What I want to do is to scan through this text file and at least make these commands seperated somehow. I thought about using some kind of clustering but I didn't use much of unsupervised learning. What could you recommend to deal with this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unsupervised approach such as clustering **cannot** work.

Because it does not know what *you* want to separate by. You have a very specific spearation in mind, making his a supervised problem (just that you have not labeled data yet).

If you want the algorithm to separate the data in the way you want it, then you'll have to **label some training data** and use a supervised approach.